# Convert Regression Coefficient in to percentange instead of sensitivity

Tags: regression, percentage

In the Multiple Linear regression i ve few independent and Dummy variable , Model fitting has done and got equation. I would like to interpret the coefficient values in terms of Percentage.

Ex.  Y = 140 + 0.25 (X1) - 2.336 (X2) + 100.23 (Dummy1) - 14.36 ( Dummy2)

these are the coefficients in Units ,I need to change the Units in to  percentage which how much effect is contributing of Y.